# SwiftUi Preview show no color

Tags: swiftui

I'm a newbie in SwiftUI and I have a little question.

I have made an Code for a Menu Bar, but when I run the Preview the "Gradient" isn't show.

Everything is white in preview.

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZNYd.png)

[preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8nq0.png)

I hope u can help me guys!

Thanks

Comment: [Please don't post your code as an image.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3933332)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
      ...
    }
}
```

to

```
struct Menu_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
      ...
    }
}
```

Comment: after the change it looks the same

Answer (score 0):

```
LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.blue, Color.red]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)
```

In the LinearGradient, you have to say Color.blue and Color.red instead of Color("blue"), Color("red").

Otherwise, you are good to go.